# Evaluate $\binom{n}{1}\alpha_1+\binom{n}{2}\alpha_2+\binom{n}{3}\alpha_3+......+\binom{n}{n}\alpha_n$

Tags: complex-numbers, summation, binomial-coefficients

If $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,.....,\alpha_n$ are the n;$n^{th}$ roots of unity then$\binom{n}{1}\alpha_1+\binom{n}{2}\alpha_2+\binom{n}{3}\alpha_3+......+\binom{n}{n}\alpha_n$

$(A)(1+\frac{\alpha_2}{\alpha_1})^n-1\hspace{1 cm}(B)\frac{\alpha_1}{2}[(1+\alpha_1)^n-1]\hspace{1cm}(C)\frac{\alpha_1+\alpha_{n-1}-1}{2}\hspace{1cm}(D)(\alpha_1+\alpha_{n-1})^n-1$

I can guess the answer for multiple choice question but dont know how to prove theoritically.Can someone guide me in this question?

Comment: The result depends on the order in which the $n^{\text{th}}$ roots of unity are listed.

Comment: That's interesting. Is there a reason as to why the result differs with different ordering of the terms?

Comment: Check with n=2.

Comment: @Khallil The coefficients are not all equal. So if we swap two roots of unity with different coefficients, we get a different sum.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The nth roots of unity are such that $\alpha_2=\alpha_1^2$ and $\alpha_3=\alpha_1^3$ and so on. The original expression is therefore equivalent to the expansion of $(1+\alpha_1)^n$ but with the first term $1$ missing. However $\frac{\alpha_2}{\alpha_1}=\alpha_1$ so the answer is A

Comment: Nice. Of course assuming that the roots are in'order'

Comment: Ha ha. It hadn't occurred to me that they might be labelled randomly

Comment: Very clever :) (+1) $\quad$

Answer (score 3):

Hint: The $n$-th roots of unity are $e^\frac{{2k\pi i}}{n}$ with $0\leq k < n$. Now apply the binomial theorem to

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\binom{n}{k}e^{\frac{2\pi k i}{n}}$$